# SparseArray indexOfValue(Object) returns different result for equal variables

Tags: java, android, android-sparsearray

As you can see in the picture bellow `latLng` is equal to `latlng1`, but `indexOfValue()` returns different values.

[image]

Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

Internally, `SparseArray` keeps values in array of [`Object`s](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/util/SparseArray.java#SparseArray.0mValues). In the [`indexOfValue(E value)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/util/SparseArray.java#SparseArray.indexOfValue%28java.lang.Object%29) method the `value` is compared with the array elements [by reference (not logical value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/513839#513839):

```
public int indexOfValue(E value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mSize; i++)
        if (mValues[i] == value)
            return i;

    return -1;
}
```

Variables `latLng` and `latlng1` refer to different objects in memory, despite they're equal logically.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code, my guess is that their lat/lng values are the same, however, they are not the same object. If using the LatLng object in the [Google APIs the equal method](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) just compares the lat and long values, not that they are the same object.

So the sparsearray only contains one of the objects and returns -1 because the other doesn't exist in the sparsearray.